# Download an image but urllib.error.HTTPError

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download an image using Python but I got the error "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". I have no clue what to do to solve the issue. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request as req
imgurl ="http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
req.urlretrieve(imgurl, r"C:\Users\home\Desktop\images\image_name.jpg")
```

Comment: It means what it says - you don't have permission. That doesn't necessarily mean it's *not* a code issue but you have to provide the real URL  you're using, or at least describe the server you're downloading from.

Comment: https://www.example.com/engine/static/articles/bear-cubs-bho/images/181212_082438_1.jpg replace "example" with "bobshideout". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `urllib`'s default user agent is the culprit. If you change it to one of a traditional browser, it works:

```
>>> opener = req.build_opener()
>>> opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36')]
>>> req.install_opener(opener)
>>> req.urlretrieve(imgurl, r"img.jpg")
('img.jpg', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x7f75aaf05a90>)
```